# сместить центр яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Есть яндекс карта(api 2.1), на карте имеется точка которая отцентрирована, и есть блок на самой карте [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сместить центр карты относительно блока?, чтобы приблизительно получилось так при том что карта адаптивная [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для созданного объекта карт

```
var map = new ymaps.map(......);
```

Получаете текущий или заданный центр в пикселях

```
var pixelCenter = map.getGlobalPixelCenter(coordinates);
```

Корректируете, например:

```
pixelCenter = [
    pixelCenter[0] - offset,
    pixelCenter[1]
];
```

Получаете координаты:

```
var geoCenter = map.options.get('projection').fromGlobalPixels(pixelCenter, map.getZoom());
```

Устанавливаете новый центр

```
map.setCenter(geoCenter);
```

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
    ymaps.ready(init);
    //Set default center and zoom
    function init() {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map_page', {
            center: [45.0701, 38.9048],
            zoom: 9
        });


        //Set user Icon
        s = {
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            iconImageHref: '/wp-content/themes/okhall/img/logo-map.svg',
            iconImageSize: [87, 74],
            iconImageOffset: [-43, -56]
        };
        //Set some points
        m = {
            m1: new ymaps.Placemark([45.0710, 38.9038], {}, s),
            m1center: [45.0701, 38.9048],
            m2: new ymaps.Placemark([45.0349, 39.1317], {}, s),
            m2center: [45.0349, 39.1317],
            m3: new ymaps.Placemark([44.7491, 37.7263], {}, s),
            m3center: [44.7491, 37.7265],
            m4: new ymaps.Placemark([45.2299, 38.1138], {}, s),
            m4center: [45.2299, 38.1138],
            m5: new ymaps.Placemark([45.8417, 40.1357], {}, s),
            m5center: [45.8417, 40.1357],
            m6: new ymaps.Placemark([44.9367, 37.9675], {}, s),
            m6center: [44.9367, 37.9675]
        };
        //Disabled scroll
        //myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
        //on mobile disable touch
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            //... отключаем перетаскивание карты
            myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');
        } 
       //Add points on the map
        myMap.geoObjects
            .add(m['m1'])
            .add(m['m2'])
            .add(m['m3'])
            .add(m['m4'])
            .add(m['m5'])
            .add(m['m6']);

        // ON RESIZE
        //Get curent center and zoom
        var pixelCenter = myMap.getGlobalPixelCenter('map_page');
        console.log(pixelCenter);

        //
        function onResizeMap() {
        if ($(window).width() > '992') { 
            //Set New center
            myMap.setCenter([45.0701, 37.0048]);
            var pixelCenter2 = myMap.getGlobalPixelCenter('map_page');
            console.log(pixelCenter2);
            } else {
                myMap.setCenter([45.0701, 38.9048]);
            }
        } onResizeMap();

        window.onresize = function () {
            onResizeMap();
        };
    };
```