# Изменить размеры карты без перемещения меток

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Возможно ли изменить размеры карты, что бы при этом она не двигалась. Что я имею ввиду. Если сейчас у контейнера в котором находится карта изменить размер (уменьшить справа на 100px) и применить

```js
Map.container.fitToViewport()
```

карта отцентруется и все метки которые на ней есть визуально «дёрнутся» и переместятся. Если не делать `fitToViewport` то визуально происходит именно тот эффект который мне нужен — карта не двигается вообще, но по факту её размер будет больше контейнера. Как можно реализовать что бы после изменения размера контейнера размер карты изменился, но не дергался, а как будто просто убрали 100px справа.

Comment: Попробовал подставлять координаты нового цента карты перед выполнением Map.container.fitToViewport() - получил минимальный рывок при изменении размера на 200px. Новый центр брал очень примерно... Попробуйте варианты: отслеживать малые изменения через событие изменения размера и подставлять новый центр или подменить центр по окончанию трансформации. Тут описан перерасчет центра: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672694/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Подогнал свою задачу под использование map.margin.Manager